# A value of type 'Iterable<Type>' can't be returned from the method 'genereMovies' because it has a return type of 'List<Type>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to separate list of movies based on their `geneType`

```
 List<Movie> genereMovies(String gene) {
    return movie.where((mov) => mov.geneType.contains(gene));
  }
```

I have this getter that will find and return Object Movie which contains that gene

my object of movie looks like this

```
Movie(
    id: 'm3',
    title: 'Golmaal 2',
    description: 'Best comedy movie by actor Ajay devgan',
    rating: '4.0/5',
    imageUrl:
        'https://pixabay.com/get/g2367e312e5b444252dd1639ba9f27edfa04e269538d22d4a5f2e843639b0f535f61d3350bd66de32d1024443ed6ee872a11db93c9ddc14035a7e73a82a4e359ab8344f145d4097cf1be4f9ee642acaf7_1920.jpg',
    geneType: ['comedy', 'action']),
```

geneType takes a list of Strings

Comment: Stick `.toList()` on the end of the `return` line. (`where` returns an iterable but that can be turned into a list.)

Answer (score 2):

The method [where](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) returns an [Iterable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable-class.html). That's why you get the error, since you want to return a `List` but you actually have an `Iterable`. The class `Iterable` has the method [toList()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) which creates a   `List`.

```
 List<Movie> genereMovies(String gene) {
    return movie.where((mov) => mov.geneType.contains(gene)).toList();
  }
```